# Create CSRF token in Django view

Tags: django, csrf

I have a particular form that is created dynamically, from a database, which I want to use in a Django template. The problem is that it requires a csrf token to be embedded. So inside my view I'd like to create this token so that I can insert it into the form there. However, I don't have any luck. This is working, partially:

```
    from django.middleware import csrf
    token = request.META.get('CSRF_COOKIE', None)
    if token is None:
        token = csrf._get_new_csrf_key()
        request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'] = token
        request.META['CSRF_COOKIE_USED'] = True
```

The first part works well -- if a token is present, it's used. However, if the token is None, and _get_new_csrf_key() is called, then it doesn't work the first time - I have to refresh the page before it works. What would be the right way to create a token inside a view?

Additional explanation:

The form is coming from a database. So I have a database record that contains the form which I read into a variable:

```
page_content = '<form>.....__csrf-placeholder__</form'
```

Then, in the template, I do:

```
{{ page_content }}
```

So that's why I can't use {% csrf_token %} inside the template. Right now, I use the replace function in the view so replace **csrf-placeholder** for the actual token. So that's why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: What about if you use `django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)`?

Comment: What do you mean with "form that is created dynamically, from a database"? Can you show what you do? Also, does the default [CSRF middleware and templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) not work in your scenario?

Comment: The form comes from a database (a CMS), so I basically have a variable called page_content = '<form>....</form>', and I simply place this inside the template by doing {{ page_content }}.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie if I run that I get `name 'django' is not defined` -- should I import something extra?

Comment: @user you're already importing the namespace so just try `get_token(request)`.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I'm getting the error `name 'get_token' is not defined`

Comment: Since you do `from django.middleware import csrf`, you can do `csrf.get_token(request)`